# Google Fit Sleep Data

Tags: android, google-fit

Not able to fetch SLEEP Data.
its provide session listing but not provide data set for sleep and all.
i am able to fetch other scope data like heart rate BPM

- Heart Rate Intensity
- Blood Pressure and all

"private void readSleepSessions() {

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);

long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();


DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(requireContext());

Log.i(TAG, "SLEEP Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
Log.i(TAG, "SLEEP Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));


SessionReadRequest request = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
        .readSessionsFromAllApps()
        .includeSleepSessions()
        .read(DataType.TYPE_SLEEP_SEGMENT)
        .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();


Fitness.getSessionsClient(requireContext(),getGoogleSigningAccount())
        .readSession(request)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SessionReadResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SessionReadResponse sessionReadResponse) {

                for (int i = 0; i < sessionReadResponse.getSessions().size(); i++) {

                    Session session = sessionReadResponse.getSessions().get(i);
                    // If the sleep session has finer granularity sub-components, extract them:
                    List<DataSet> dataSets = sessionReadResponse.getDataSet(session);

                    for (int j = 0; j < dataSets.size(); j++) {
                        DataSet mDataSet = dataSets.get(j);
                        for (DataPoint point : mDataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                            String sleepStageVal = "" + point.getValue(Field.FIELD_SLEEP_SEGMENT_TYPE).asInt();
                            long segmentStart = point.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                            long segmentEnd = point.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                            Log.i(TAG, "\t* Type $sleepStage between $segmentStart and $segmentEnd" + segmentStart + "" + segmentEnd);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        });}"
```

Thanks in advance.